# PowerMockito whenNew returns null

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

In the source class that which I can't refactor (so i can't use advices [here](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/Mocking-Object-Creation)) there are object creations with = new XXX. And i have to mock their function calls X().call().

For this purpose i am using powermock's whenNew() function. But i am having null in the class that i am testing which is LoginSuccessHandler in this case. Here my LoginSuccessHandlerTest class:

```java
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class LoginSuccessHandlerTest {

    @InjectMocks private LoginSuccessHandler loginSuccessHandler;
    @Mock private GuiSessionDAO guiSessionDAO;
    @Mock private UserAuthorityDAO userAuthorityDAO;
    @Mock private OrcaAuthorizationServiceBean orcaAuthorizationServiceBean;
    @Mock private OrcaAuthorizationServiceBeanService orcaAuthorizationServiceBeanService;
    @Mock private GetUserRolesReturnModel userRolesReturnModel;

    private Authentication authentication;
    private MockHttpServletRequest request;
    private MockHttpServletResponse response;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
        authentication = new TestingAuthenticationToken("foo", "foo", "foo");
    }

    @PrepareForTest({LoginSuccessHandler.class})
    @Test
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess() throws Exception {



        whenNew(OrcaAuthorizationServiceBeanService.class).withArguments(URL.class).thenReturn(orcaAuthorizationServiceBeanService);

        p("Mocking Orca WS calls");
        when(orcaAuthorizationServiceBeanService.getOrcaAuthorizationServiceBeanPort()).thenReturn(orcaAuthorizationServiceBean);
        when(orcaAuthorizationServiceBean.getUserRoles(any(Header.class), anyString())).thenReturn(userRolesReturnModel);
        when(userRolesReturnModel.getUserRoles()).thenReturn(Collections.singletonList("ADMIN"));

        p("Starting mock log in");
        loginSuccessHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);

        assertEquals(MockHttpServletResponse.SC_OK, response.getStatus());
    }

    private void p(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

And here i get null

```
OrcaAuthorizationServiceBeanService service = new OrcaAuthorizationServiceBeanService(new URL(url));
```

When i debug, i can confirm that powermockito is running to mock this object creation and this method is being called:

```
public static synchronized NewInvocationControl<?> putNewInstanceControl(Class<?> type, NewInvocationControl<?> control) {
        return newSubstitutions.put(type, control);
    }
```

And those are the parameters:

```
type = {Class@1755} "class com.ttech.timsgui.ldap.OrcaAuthorizationServiceBeanService"
 cachedConstructor = null
 newInstanceCallerCache = null
 name = "com.ttech.timsgui.ldap.OrcaAuthorizationServiceBeanService"
 classLoader = {MockClassLoader@2118} 
 reflectionData = {SoftReference@2119} 
 classRedefinedCount = 0
 genericInfo = null
 enumConstants = null
 enumConstantDirectory = null
 annotationData = null
 annotationType = null
 classValueMap = null
control = {MockitoNewInvocationControl@2093} 
 substitute = {InvocationSubstitute$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$4d9f6379@2109} "invocationSubstitute"
  CGLIB$BOUND = true
  CGLIB$CALLBACK_0 = {PowerMockMethodInterceptorFilter@2115} 
  CGLIB$CALLBACK_1 = {SerializableNoOp@2116}
```

And here is the result when it hits the getter:

```
public static synchronized NewInvocationControl<?> getNewInstanceControl(Class<?> type) {
    return newSubstitutions.get(type);
}

type = {Class@277} "class java.net.URL"
newSubstitutions = {HashMap@1823}  size = 1
 0 = {HashMap$Node@2195} "class com.ttech.timsgui.ldap.OrcaAuthorizationServiceBeanService" -> 
  key = {Class@1755} "class com.ttech.timsgui.ldap.OrcaAuthorizationServiceBeanService"
  value = {MockitoNewInvocationControl@2137}
```

this returns null and object creation returns null too. What causes this problem?

Comment: You should change you production code so that it gets the instance of `OrcaAuthorizationServiceBeanService` injected. Then you could mock it with plain Mockito.

Comment: As i said inn the first sentence, i cant change production code and use plain mockito. It is why i am using powermockito

Comment: have u initialized mocks with `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);`

Comment: I agree with pvpkiran - looking at the code you are showing, you missed the fact that the PowerMockRunner will probably **not** init the Mockito @Mock annotated mocks.

Comment: I added and retried now, still returns null. It looks like that it can't find constructor with new URL(url) which is am calling whenNew(OrcaAuthorizationServiceBeanService.class).withArguments(URL.class)

Comment: You _may_ need to add OrcaAuthorizationServiceBeanService.class to @PrepareForTest

Comment: You've handled the new object creation for OrcaAuthorizationServiceBeanService class but not for the URL class. Notice that when an object of OrcaAuthorizationServiceBeanService is created, a new instance of URL class is also created in the constructor parameter. Write a whenNew() for URL class and try

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
whenNew(OrcaAuthorizationServiceBeanService.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(orcaAuthorizationServiceBeanService);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18757839)

Comment: This problem can be solved by using 'withAnyArguments' rather than using 'withArguments'